# Create resource for each value in a map

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to create a resource for each value in a map.

For example, I need to create a `azuread_application_password` resource. I would like a new secret per user of the application, so I have created a map that container the person using the application, and which parts of the application they can have access to:

```
variable "users" {
  type        = map(list(string))
}

users = {"user_1" : ["area_1", "area_2"], "user_2" : ["area_3", "area_4"]}
```

The value in the map also corresponds to the name of the application created via a `azuread_application`

```
resource "azuread_application_password" "client_secret" {
  for_each              = var.users
  display_name          = "Secret-${each.key}"
  application_object_id = azuread_application.auth[each.value].object_id
}
```

I would like to end up with an `azuread_application_password` created for each value in the map, and the display name to be the key.

The above block does not work because `each.value` is a `list(string)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **flatten** your map:

```
locals {
  users_flat = merge([
            for user, areas in var.users: {
              for area in areas:
                "${user}-${area}" => {
                    "area" = area
                    "user" = user
                }
            }
        ]...)
}
```

then

```
resource "azuread_application_password" "client_secret" {
  for_each              = local.users_flat
  display_name          = "Secret-${each.value.user}"
  application_object_id = azuread_application.auth[each.value.area].object_id
}
```

Comment: Huh that's pretty cool! Is that doing what is described here?
https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/flatten#flattening-nested-structures-for-for_each

Comment: @CJW Yes, its flattening, but using `merge`, not `flatten` (there are many ways for flattening, not only `flatten`).